# Calling php script using C# (Unity)

Tags: c#, php, mysql, unity-game-engine

I'm fairly new to both Unity and PHP, and I am currently working on a project where I can parse data from a MySQL database to Unity, using PHP.

I initially wanted to try and enable a method where the user can perhaps change the php script and enable it to choose a different table of data, however I was advised that it may be safer to list all variables within the php script and call it from Unity accordingly;

Display.php

```
$table = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['table'], $db);

if ($table == "shoes") { 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `shoes` ORDER by `price` ASC LIMIT 10";

elseif ($table == "sneakers") { 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `sneakers` ORDER by `price` ASC LIMIT 10";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);  

for($i = 0; $i < $num_results; $i++)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo $row['shopname'] . "\t" . $row['price'] . "\n";
}
```

I'm having trouble calling the php and choosing the table that I want to select, I am pretty new to this, so I apologise if this seems completely incompetent to you guys.

Here is the my Unity Script;

HSController.cs

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(GetScores());
}

// remember to use StartCoroutine when calling this function!
IEnumerator PostScores(string name, int score)
{

    string hash = Md5Sum(name + score + secretKey);

    string post_url = addScoreURL + "name=" + WWW.EscapeURL(name) + "&score=" + score + "&hash=" + hash;

    WWW hs_post = new WWW(post_url);
    yield return hs_post; // Wait until the download is done

    if (hs_post.error != null)
    {
        print("There was an error posting the high score: " + hs_post.error);
    }
}

IEnumerator GetScores()
{
    gameObject.guiText.text = "Loading...";
    WWW hs_get = new WWW(highscoreURL);
    yield return hs_get;

    if (hs_get.error != null)
    {
        print("There was an error getting the high score: " + hs_get.error);
    }
    else
    {
        gameObject.guiText.text = hs_get.text; // this is a GUIText that will display the scores in game.
    }
}
```

Any help or a point in the right direction would be great!

Kind Regards

Comment: For which platform are you developing ? if win then you can try to use 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest'

Comment: I'm developing it for an iPhone and Andriod Application

Comment: In the sample code you posted you don't send or set the `table` `GET` variable

Comment: @AeroX Apologise, I'm not too sure what to do there? any suggestions?

Comment: @user1809075 In the PHP section you read the `table` variable `$_GET['table']` but you don't appear to set that in the C# code.

Comment: Two `}` are missing in your PHP code, for the `if` and the `elseif` statements respectively.

Comment: i am getting empty reply from server? do you know the reason

Answer (score 2):

Let me try to rewrite this into a working example:

### C#

```
void Start() {
    StartCoroutine(GetData());
}


IEnumerator GetData() {
    gameObject.guiText.text = "Loading...";
    WWW www = new WWW("http://yoururl.com/yourphp.php?table=shoes"); //GET data is sent via the URL

    while(!www.isDone && string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error)) {
        gameObject.guiText.text = "Loading... " + www.Progress.ToString("0%"); //Show progress
        yield return null;
    }

    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error)) gameObject.guiText.text = www.text;
    else Debug.LogWarning(www.error);
}
```

### PHP

```
<?php

//DB connection goes here

if ($_REQUEST['table'] === "shoes") { //I'm using REQUEST instead of GET, so it will work with both GET and POST
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `shoes` ORDER by `price` ASC LIMIT 10";
} elseif ($_REQUEST['table'] === "sneakers") { 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `sneakers` ORDER by `price` ASC LIMIT 10";
}

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo  $row['shopname'] . "\t" . $row['price'] . "\n"; 
}
?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i am getting empty reply from server? do you know the reason