# Integrate Augmented Reality app with database

Tags: android, augmented-reality, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm quite new to `AR` and `Unity3D`, but I've learnt how to create simple `AR` app using `Vuforia SDK` for `Unity`. Till now I can work with 3D object, image target and export into `Android` project.

Now, my question is: How can I use database (`MySql`, `Sqlite`, etc.) with the AR? For example, I'd like to show some information retrieved from db on my 3D object in Android application.

I am not sure should this be implemented either in Unity or Android solution? I also could not find any relevant tutorial and would appreciate any advice.

**Edit:**
More on database

It primarily would contain text data, link to images which will be located on the remote server as well as database itself. Preferably, it should be MySql database. On the other hand, I will use `RESTful` web services.
I know I can use all this in Android project, but how can I access the 3D object within the code?

Comment: What type of information does the database contain? Is this a database running on a remote server. The info you provide about the database, the better response you'll get.

Comment: @Programmer, you're right, see my edit

Comment: Your edit made sense until **but how can I access the 3D object within the code?** Can you explain that?

Comment: I mean, once I get Android solution being exported, I want to display some data retrieved from db on 3D object that I created in Unity. How can I position labels, images, etc. on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the webserver side, you can use php or any other language. The recommended one is php so you have to learn php.

For your main app, you can use Unity, use the `[WWW][1]` class to connect to the server. When connected to the server, the php script will retrieve information from the database and send it back to Unity. This supports texts, images, audio and many others.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25200894/3785314
http://www.cs.vu.nl/~eliens/.CREATE/local/essay/09/nm2/klitsie-joost.pdf

Comment: So, if I'm right the data can be bound to Unity UI elements. Is it possible to use Android UI within Android project? I know php, C# and a bit of Java, and thanks for the references, very helpful.

Comment: Yes you can put anything to Unity UI just like every other API. Just learn Unity UI. https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsZM3q74Q2k