# Interacting with database Unity3D and Dapper c#

Tags: c#, database, unity-game-engine

I wanted to interacting with database using Dapper [[Link]](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net), I have created a connection and select statement to table in database, it will return a bunch of string variables and I stored it into List, then it will convert to JSON first, before it returns. But, whenever I want to connect to database, it hit error message:

```
SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

Here is the code itself:

**Dev.cs**

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using Newtonsoft.Json;
 using DataAccessLayer.Models.Member;
 using DataAccessLayer;

 public class Dev : MonoBehaviour
 {
     private List<MemberRepository> Lists = null;

     private void Start()
     {
         Lists = DataAccess_Member.Instance.RetrieveLanguage(new MemberRepository()).ToList();

         var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Lists);

         Debug.Log(serialized);
     }
 }
```

**DataAccess_Member.cs**

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 using DataAccessLayer.Models.Member;

 namespace DataAccessLayer
 {
     public class DataAccess_Member
     {
         private static DataAccess_Member _instance = null;

         public static DataAccess_Member Instance
         {
             get
             {
                 if (_instance == null)
                 {
                     _instance = new DataAccess_Member();
                 }

                 return _instance;
             }
         }

         public IEnumerable<MemberRepository> RetrieveLanguage(MemberRepository repository)
         {
             try
             {
                 string query = "SELECT [Language], [LanguageCode] FROM [LanguageGroup] WITH (NOLOCK) ORDER BY [Language] ASC";

                 return DatabaseHelper.Instance.Find(query, repository);
             }

             catch (SqlException ex)
             {
                 return null;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

**Member Model**

```
 namespace DataAccessLayer.Models.Member
 {
     public class MemberRepository
     {
         public string Language { get; set; }
         public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
     }
 }
```

**DatabaseHelper.cs**

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 using Dapper;

 namespace DataAccessLayer
 {
     public class DatabaseHelper
     {
         private static DatabaseHelper _instance = null;

         private string connectionString = @"Data Source=MSI\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=ID;Password=Password";

         public static DatabaseHelper Instance
         {
             get
             {
                 if (_instance == null)
                 {
                     _instance = new DatabaseHelper();
                 }

                 return _instance;
             }
         }

         public IEnumerable<T> Find<T>(string query, T models)
         {
             using (IDbConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
             {
                 conn.Open();

                 return conn.Query<T>(query, models);
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Is this the right method to interacting with database in Unity and is the error message means it is forbidden to connect directly between client and server? What is the right thing to do to connecting to database with Unity?

I have been thinking to create a generic handler (web service in the DataAccessLayer namespace (as DataAccessLayer is different project, and I used DLL as reference to that), and in unity call that generic handler I have created with WWW, But, I have to publish the generic handler into live website first, before make it work, isn't it?

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Your answer much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This has been asked over and over again and is the wrong way to do this. Please take a look at the links in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39140295/3785314). Your database code should never be executed on the client side. It should be executed on the server with php or perl then you use WWW to communicate with them. Also, using Json is fine for this.

Comment: @Programmer: Hi, is there any reason why I should interacting to database with php or perl? (This only applies for Unity3D engine isn't it?) Anyhow, I will look at the link you have provided.

Comment: No, but they are the most used languages on the server side this days. You get more support if you use them. What do you want to do? Use Javascript to interact with your database?

Comment: @Programmer: hmm, okay then, will try to use PHP and WWW with Unity. Thank you, you're a big help.