# Value Is too large

Tags: c#, sql, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a plugin with SQL and I get some errors which I don't know what to do with them. SQL Database manager + adding the player from the main class.

```
  private void Events_OnPlayerConnected(UnturnedPlayer player)
        {
            FriendsGroupID_t id;
            id.m_FriendsGroupID = (short)player.SteamGroupID.m_SteamID;
            Database.addPlayer(player.CharacterName, player.SteamName, SteamFriends.GetFriendsGroupName(id), player.CSteamID.m_SteamID.ToString());
        }
```

Other code:

```
using System;
using I18N.West;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using Rocket.Core.Logging;
using Steamworks;

namespace SQLPlayer
{

    internal class DatabaseController
    {

        private MySqlConnection createConnection()
        {
            MySqlConnection Connection = null;
            try
            {
                if (SQLPlayer.Instance.Configuration.Instance.DatabasePort == 0)
                {
                    SQLPlayer.Instance.Configuration.Instance.DatabasePort = 3306;
                }
                Connection = new MySqlConnection(string.Format("SERVER={0};DATABASE={1};UID={2};PASSWORD={3};PORT={4};", new object[]
                {
                    SQLPlayer.Instance.Configuration.Instance.DatabaseAddress,
                    SQLPlayer.Instance.Configuration.Instance.DatabaseName,
                    SQLPlayer.Instance.Configuration.Instance.DatabaseUsername,
                    SQLPlayer.Instance.Configuration.Instance.DatabasePassword,
                    SQLPlayer.Instance.Configuration.Instance.DatabasePort
                }));
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
            return Connection;
        }


        public DatabaseController()
        {
            new CP1250();
            CheckSchema();
        }


        internal void CheckSchema()
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = createConnection();
                MySqlCommand mySqlCommand = mySqlConnection.CreateCommand();
                mySqlCommand.CommandText = "show tables like '" + SQLPlayer.Instance.Configuration.Instance.LogTableName + "'";
                mySqlConnection.Open();
                if (mySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() == null)
                {
                    mySqlCommand.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE `" + SQLPlayer.Instance.Configuration.Instance.LogTableName + "` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `player_display_name` TEXT NOT NULL , `player_steam_name` TEXT NOT NULL ,`player_steamgroup_name` TEXT NOT NULL , `player_steam_id` INT NOL NULL , `sent_on` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , PRIMARY KEY (`id`));";
                    mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                mySqlConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogException(ex);
            }
        }

        // Token: 0x06000006 RID: 6 RVA: 0x00002250 File Offset: 0x00000450
        public void addPlayer(string charactername, string steamname , string steamgroupname , int steamid)
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = createConnection();
                MySqlCommand mySqlCommand = mySqlConnection.CreateCommand();
                mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@steamname", steamname);
                mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@charactername", charactername);
                mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@steamgroupname", steamgroupname);
                mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@steamid", steamid);
                string commandText = "insert into `" + SQLPlayer.Instance.Configuration.Instance.LogTableName + "` (`player_display_name` , `player_steam_name`,`player_steamgroup_name`,`player_steam_id`) values(@charactername,@steamname , @steamgroupname ,@steamid);";
                mySqlCommand.CommandText = commandText;
                mySqlConnection.Open();
                mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                mySqlConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }


        public void DeletePlayers()
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = createConnection();
                MySqlCommand mySqlCommand = mySqlConnection.CreateCommand();
                DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-SQLPlayer.Instance.Configuration.Instance.DeleteAfterDays);
                mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@days", dateTime);
                string commandText = "DELETE FROM " + SQLPlayer.Instance.Configuration.Instance.LogTableName + " WHERE `last_login` > @date; ";
                mySqlCommand.CommandText = commandText;
                mySqlConnection.Open();
                mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                mySqlConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I am getting when I am calling the fuction `addPlayer`:

```
 Error in MulticastDelegate PlayerConnected: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.OverflowException: Value is too large
  at System.Int16.Parse (System.String s) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at SQLPlayer.SQLPlayer.Events_OnPlayerConnected (Rocket.Unturned.Player.UnturnedPlayer player) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl (System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl (System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke (System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Rocket.Core.Extensions.MulticastDelegateExtension.TryInvoke (System.MulticastDelegate theDelegate, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: Your exception is in `Events_OnPlayerConnected`, not in `addPlayer`. The stack trace tells you this.

Comment: The error is pretty clear, you are trying to stuff a number into an Int16 that is too large to hold an Int16. You might need an Int32 (`int`) or even an Int64 (`long`)

Comment: @DavidG What I need to do?

Comment: @Plugin4U No idea, you didn't show us the code that is causing the problem...

Comment: @DavidG Check now.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `player.SteamGroupID.m_SteamID` is going to fit inside a `short` variable? Because that's where your error is.

Comment: @Plugin4U Just to let you know that you are doing this wrong. I see what you are doing but the proper way is to run the SQL code in your server not on the client. You will end up redoing all this. Please stop now and start over with the proper way. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39140295/3785314)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is this line:

```
id.m_FriendsGroupID = (short)player.SteamGroupID.m_SteamID;
```

The `m_SteamID` value is likely an `int` and too large to fit inside a variable of type `short`. The best solution here would be to make sure `id.m_FriendsGroupID` is also of type `int` and remove the cast to `short`.

Comment: private void Events_OnPlayerConnected(UnturnedPlayer player)
        {
            FriendsGroupID_t id;
            id.m_FriendsGroupID = Convert.ToInt16(player.SteamGroupID.m_SteamID);
            Convert.ToInt32(player.CSteamID.m_SteamID);
        }

Comment: You are *still* trying to convert to a short (Convert.ToInt16), just leave it as int or long.