# Connecting Unity to Local MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a server in Unity that at the moment connects to a local database on my computer.

```
void Start()
    {

        using (SqlConnection dbCon = new SqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;" +
                                                        "Database=bomberman;uid=root"))
        {
            //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(_query, dbCon);
            try
            {
                dbCon.Open();
                Debug.Log("Successfully opened MySQL");
                //string _returnQuery = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            catch (SqlException _exception)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning(_exception.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

At the moment, I wanted to keep it simple so I left the credentials as barebones as possible so that I can confirm a connection can exist; however, I'm getting a

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Furthermore, I can confirm that I can connect to MySQL from other sources since I was able to host a game server using this particular connection previously. Any ideas?

Comment: Not worth answering because you will have to redo this if you get it working. Take a moment and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39140068/how-to-connect-to-a-mssql-server-database-through-unity3d-editor-standalone/39140295#39140295)

Comment: @Programmer even if this SQL is done server side, not client? I noticed with most comments developers were trying to connect from game client side.

Comment: SqlConnection is for SQL Server, not MySQL

Comment: *"I noticed with most comments developers were trying to connect from game client side"* They are doing it wrong. MySQL should only be done on the server side with php, perl or which ever language you chose. You are currently doing this through Unity. It will take less than 5 minutes for someone to de-compile that, retrieve the MySQL server IP, username, password then use it against you.

Comment: @Programmer What I meant with that quote was that the issue often lay with people trying to write database connections on client side, but I'm trying to write one for server side. Does this change the problem at all, even if what I'm trying to do is server side and not client?

Comment: *"but I'm trying to write one for server side*" If that's the case, then you should never release it. This code should only be running on a computer/server only you have access to. That's fine. If you release it as a game/app then everything I just said still apply. Some would say "worry about security later" but this is totally different since you will have to re-write it all.

Comment: I'm attempting to write a separate client - server Unity application (not sure if this is the correct way of doing it) but at the moment I'm just having basic communication between the client and server with the server saving whenever I specify so. Game clients will be released separately and used to connect to the live server.

If there is no problem with this given this knowledge, how should I proceed? Someone above said I was using the wrong library and he was write, but now I need to import the MySql dll

Comment: As long as that server with the MySQL code is running on your computer and not released to the public that should be fine. By the way, I don't know why anyone would use Unity to make the server code for the database. You will have hard time doing this because you need MySQL.data.dll. Unity uses old version of Mono making it harder to find MySQL.data.dll compatible with it.

Comment: Follow the installation steps [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-installation-windows.html) for setting it up. You will need to install Unity 2017 in order to use .Net 4.5 For connecting tutorials, go [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-open.html)