# How do I connect to a Local MSSQL Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, unity-game-engine

EDIT: I've just tested it in ASP.NET and it works perfectly fine. So no issue with the connection string or anything. Guess Unity doesn't like this method? Maybe there's some more DLL's I need to copy? Any ideas?

So I'm making a game in Unity and I'm trying to use the System.Data.SqlClient library to connect to some stored procedures I have made for things such as registering a user.

I have copied the System.Data.dll from "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\unity" and that has all worked fine.

I'm currently using this connection string, which works fine on an ASP.NET application but just using a different mdf:

```
private string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\uppy8\Desktop\Computer Science Project\Mining Game\Assets\MineRace.mdf';Integrated Security = True";
```

The problem occurs when running this code:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

public void Login()
{
    Crypto crypto = new Crypto();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log(e);
        }

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("USERS_LOGIN_USER", conn);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Username", usernameInputField.text));

        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (crypto.EncryptString(passwordInputField.text) == reader["password"].ToString())
                {
                    UserAccountManager.instance.userInfo = FetchUserInfo((int)reader["id"]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem happens on the line "conn.Open()", where Unity gives me the error:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known.
```

Furthermore, without the try catch, the error occurs where I create a new SqlDataReader, where I get this issue:

```
InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader requires an open connection to continue. This connection is closed.
```

I understand that this is an issue with the connection, in that it's not running or the connection isn't working properly, however I can't seem to find a solution and I have a sneaky suspicion that it's something to do with Unity not supporting this library.

Some more clarification just before I end off:

- The user enters their credentials into the "usernameInputField" and "passwordInputField"
- The user presses Login, which runs the "Login" method shown above
- The error occurs.

If any more information is required please leave a comment.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you test connect to "(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB" database with ssms ?

Comment: Yes. In fact, I created it with ssms. Another database which I'm using for testing my ASP.NET website is also on the same server.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39140068/how-to-connect-to-a-mssql-server-database-through-unity3d-editor-standalone/39140295#39140295) post for proper way to connect to a database if you want to release your game later on. Don't connect to your database from your app directly.

Comment: I won't be publishing the application in it's current state anywhere. I'm just using it for my computer science coursework as a proof of concept. In fact, I used to use this method before with the same project, but my hosting ran out for the website and I don't have money to buy new hosting. Plus, that method had issues that I didn't know how to solve.

Comment: Too many excuses. 1.You can create a local server with Apache and still use that solution without paying. 2.Even if it's not ready to be published, you should still do it the right way at this moment otherwise you will have to re-write your whole code. 3.Even when a coursework, you have to prove to your professor that you understand using Restful to access server is very important than hardcoding it in your program. Maybe some profs don't care, mine did. Anyways, this is not an answer and I was just trying to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What is the scope of connectionString?  Do you need to pass the connectionString to the Login() function?

```
public void Login(string connectionString)
```

I am a DBA, not a .Net developer, so forgive me if my questions are too basic or if my .Net syntax is wrong.

Comment: The variable will be available through the whole script as I declared it outside any methods. Plus, I logged the connection string to the console right before the connection is made to test if it's the same, and it was.

Comment: (1 of 2) I just noticed that you set "Integrated Security" to true.  That setting is for using Windows authentication, which I do not believe will work with SQL Server (a.k.a. "mixed") authentication (passing credentials into the instance).  To verify your authentication mode, these queries should help: "SELECT CASE SERVERPROPERTY('IsIntegratedSecurityOnly')   
WHEN 1 THEN 'Windows Authentication'   
WHEN 0 THEN 'Windows and SQL Server Authentication'   
END as [Authentication Mode] \n EXEC master.sys.xp_loginconfig 'login mode'  "

Comment: (2 of 2) If the queries show "Windows and SQL Server Authentication" or "Mixed," try setting Integrated Security to false, or deleting that part of your connection string.  Next, check to make sure your login has access to your database: "use master \n select * from sys.sql_logins where name='usernameInputField' \n use MSSQLLocalDB
 \n select * from sys.database_principals where name='usernameInputField'". Finally, since you have another database on the same server, try changing your connectionString to the other database, use its credentials, and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source = (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog ='C:\USERS\uppy8\Desktop\Computer Science Project\Mining Game\Assets\MineRace.mdf'; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30; Encrypt = False; TrustServerCertificate = True; ApplicationIntent = ReadWrite; MultiSubnetFailover = False"
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();   
                    if (con.State==ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        con.Close();
                        con.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        con.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                    }
```