# Does Unity's System.Data support SQL Server connection strings?

Tags: c#, sql-server, unity-game-engine

Whenever I am trying to establish my connection to the SQL Server database, I am getting this error

> ArgumentException: Keyword not supported : 'trustservercertificate'.

I tried to searching google on this error and there doesn't seem to be any relevant results. Since in unity to use the `System.Data` dll you have to use the one that is provided with the unity distribution I was wondering if perhaps the the encryption for SQL Server is not supported by the unity version of the dll.  If anybody has any suggestions of a solution or for a work around I would be very grateful. I am including my code for my database object in case it is just a case that I have a bug in my code that I am not seeing.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class DataBase
{
    private string CurrentDB;
    private SqlConnection connection;
    private SqlCommand command;

    public DataBase(string connectionString)
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    public void Open()
    {
        connection.Open();
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        connection.Close();
    }

    public bool SetDB(string dbName)
    {
        CurrentDB = dbName;
        return SelectDB();
    }

    public string GetDB()
    {
        return CurrentDB;
    }

    private bool SelectDB()
    {
        string query = "use " + CurrentDB + ";";
        return Command(query);
    }

    public SqlDataReader Query(string sql)
    {
        SqlDataReader reader;
        Open();
        command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        command.Dispose();
        Close();
        return reader;
    }

    public bool Command(string sql)
    {
        Open();
        command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

        try
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }

        command.Dispose();
        Close();
        return true;
    }
}
```

My connection string is this

```
Data Source=LAPTOP;Integrated Security=False;User ID=username;Password=********;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False
```

Comment: Why do you need to use database in unity?

Comment: I am creating a procedurally generated space game that is may have thousands of procedurally generated unique objects.  As well there are many other game objects that each have individual stats properties and relationships that need to be tracked.  I also want to be able to have multiple players working from the same 'Galaxy' using all the same objects.  I suppose that there are other options for achieving all of this but a database seems like the most obvious out of the box solution.

Comment: I am not saying using database is bad. You are just using it the wrong way. Don't connect to it directly from your Unity app. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39140068) post for how to use database in Unity.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I was just hoping I could test my database functions in unity to bench test them before adding the middleman in there.  I will mark this solution is correct once I have time to set up a solution using php.

Comment: You can't accept or mark the answer as correct since I left the answer on another question not your(this) question but you can up-vote it. I might mark this question as a duplicate. Regardless, do the database test from php and save your time.