# How to fix error KeyNotFoundException. Unity SQL in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, unity-game-engine

How to fix the error `KeyNotFoundException The given key was not present in the dictionary.` connect with localhost in C# unity

I don't know what cause error in `ExecuteReader` and `MySqlDataReader` is null.

```
private MySqlCommand cmd;
private MySqlDataReader rmd;

void getdata(MySqlConnection _conn)
{

    string sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
     cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, _conn);
    rmd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (rmd.Read())
    {
        string d1 = (string)rmd["username"];
        string d2 = (string)rmd["country"];

        Debug.Log(d1);
        Debug.Log(d2);
    }
}
```

Following are my database setting

[image: setting]

and error message

[image: error]

Comment: Consider embedding images.

Comment: @TomAranda he can't. He does not have enough reputation yet.

Comment: @SuitBoyApps.  Fair point.  That comment was intended for whoever picks this up off of the "requires editing" queue, or I may take care of it myself.

Comment: Post your code and the error instead of screenshots. Note that you shouldn't connect to the database directly. Use RESTful to do that. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39140068/how-to-connect-to-a-mssql-server-database-through-unity3d-editor-standalone/39140295#39140295)

Comment: @TomAranda I gotcha. I was in that queue. I just tried to edit it but because he made no effort to ask a well-formatted question and posted screenshots of the code instead of adding the code to the question StackOverflow will not let me save my edits

Comment: @mark yotawut please read this article prior to posting another question. Stack overflow wants you to post your code in the text box and not through a screenshot as well as a better description.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @SuitBoyApps: I just made an edit.  I agree he should cut and paste his code directly.  I'm not ready to go through that effort tonight.  :)

Comment: Please share your data base field and data too.