# Properly encrypt a Database String in a Unity Project

Tags: c#, database, unity-game-engine, encryption, connection-string

So I want to connect to a database from an enduser application made in Unity, because you could decompile the project and get the string from there what would be really bad. So I tried to encrypt it somehow. I already tried to find solutions, but they were only for ASP.NET or Windows Forms.

What I tried so far was creating an App.config with a RSA encyrpted Connection string made with `aspnet_regiss.exe`. But the program didn't want to start up. Also the database is on a Server and not on the local PC.

Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: If the application can decrypt the connection string, so can a sufficiently well motivated attacker, if the code is running on the attacker's machine. You need to introduce a *server* into your architecture (`client app <-> server <-> database system`) if you don't want someone gaining direct access to the DB.

Comment: If you encrypt on the client then it is too easy to decrypt. You probably want to send the data to a web service to be encrypted.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Well I used bair bones Sockets, that's why I wanted to switch. Since it randomly shutdown itself and similar. Also it was the only way that I found how to use Async Data Transfer.

Comment: Your client should not have direct access to the DB. Access should be mediated by a web-service (probably WebAPI) and clients should do the OAuth2 dance to get access.

Comment: Okay I see, is it possible to run a c# console app and a Asp.Net application at the same time on a Ubuntu Linux server? Also you can create an answer, I will mark it as correct, thanks for the help. @spender

Comment: @Twenty I'm not going as far as an answer because this only one (opinionated) way to keep things secure. It doesn't answer your specific question.

Comment: Okay anyway thanks a lot!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39140068/3785314) has an example on how to connect to database in Unity